# Visual Studio 2015 Preview breaks SQL Server hierarchyid

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

After installing VS2015, SQL Server can no longer call ToString() method for hierarchyid CLR type - for some values it works, for others it throws the following exception:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined
>   routine or aggregate "hierarchyid": 
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.HierarchyIdException: 24000: SqlHierarchyId
>   operation failed because HierarchyId object was constructed from an
>   invalid binary string.

This is easily reproduced by running the following simple query:

> select OrganizationNode.ToString() from HumanResources.Employee

I tried uninstalling .NET 4.5.3, but it didn't help. Any known workarounds? Trying to CAST the hierarchyid value to VARCHAR resulted with the same error, so I assume it calls ToString() under the hood.

Comment: Try uninstalling "Microsoft SQL Server System CLR types" or what it is called in VS 2015.

Comment: @GSerg how can I do that?

Comment: Go to Control Panel - Programs and Features, find and uninstall? Or launch the VS installer, select to change the installation and untick SQL Server data types in the features set?

Comment: @GSerg did that, restarted SQL server, still broken (note: I uninstalled VS 2015, there was no new version of SQL CLR types installed at the same time as I installed VS 2015)

Comment: @GSerg What version of the CLR types should I have? (Currently have : 12.0.2360.19 and 12.0.2369.29)

Comment: I've no idea, and arguably it depends on the SQL Server version. You can try download the known-good packages ([2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065), [2014](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295)). Have you restarted the server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67434/discussion-between-soandos-and-gserg).

Comment: @GSerg also, I can't seem to unload the types dll (i.e. no matter what I do the types still seem to be defined)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it didn't help. I removed CLR types for SQL Server 2014, as that was what I was using. Restarted, no change.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1063935/visual-studio-2015-breaks-hierarchyid-clr-type

Comment: @soandos and Damir: the version # refers in part to the version of SQL Server that they go with. `10.50.xxxx` are for 2008 R2, `11.x.xxxx` are for 2012, and `12.x.xxxx` are for 2014. I have VS 2012 Community, SQL Server 2012, and CLR types versions `11.1.3366.16`, `11.2.5058.0`, and `12.0.2000.8`. The test query in the question works fine for me. The CLR types are not a part of Visual Studio; they are part of SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools). Try uninstalling Data Tools and then the types.

Comment: @srutzky does not work. Other ideas?

Comment: @soandos You are using SQL Server 2014? I assume this is a local instance, either Express or Express LocalDB? Have you tried running the installer for whichever one it is again and doing a repair (if that is available)?

Comment: @srutzky This is not express, this is the dev version

Comment: @soandos Ok, forgot about that. But same thing (i.e. a locally running instance). Can you try running the installer on it and see if there is a repair option?

Comment: @srutzky does nothing.

Comment: @soandos Hmm. What version of AdventureWorks are you testing against?

Comment: @srutzky I'm actually testing against the code in the ms connect bug as there are no dependencies in that

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio 2015 CTP6 fixes this.

Edit: Changed CTP5 (which did fix it for a short while) to CTP6, which fixes it permanently for me.